# Empty box created when inserting a table using XMLCursor to XWPFDocument

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

When I inset a table into a XWPFDocument using an XMLCursor it is inserting the table into the correct position but it is adding an extra box under the first column.  The box is joined onto the table so it looks like it is an additional table cell but when I insert the table without using and XMLCursor the table is correct and the box is at the position of the XMLCursor.  Is there any way to delete the box as it looks like its an additional table cell.

```
    XWPFDocument part1Document = new XWPFDocument(part1Package);
    XmlCursor xmlCursor = part1Document.getDocument().getBody().getPArray(26).newCursor();

       //create first row
     XWPFTable tableOne = part1Document.createTable();

        XWPFTableRow tableOneRowOne = tableOne.getRow(0);
        tableOneRowOne.getCell(0).setText("Hello");
        tableOneRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("World");

        XWPFTableRow tableOneRowTwo = tableOne.createRow();
        tableOneRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("This is");
        tableOneRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("a table");

        tableOne.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText("only text");


       XmlCursor c2 = tableOne.getCTTbl().newCursor();

       c2.moveXml(xmlCursor);

       c2.dispose();
        XWPFTable tables = part1Document.insertNewTbl(xmlCursor);
       xmlCursor.dispose();
```

The empty box is appearing at the position of the 26th paragraph. Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is you actually create two different tables. The first one with method `createTable()`, then you add rows and cells needed. After that at the cursor on your table `tableOne`you create a new table with method `insertNewTbl(xmlCursor)`. The method creates a new table with 1 row and 1 cell, hence your empty box.

I can't say why your first table is actually placed in the correct position, probably because it is merged with the second table, that goes to your cursor.

I suggest you create the second table from the start:

```
XWPFTable tableOne = part1Document.insertNewTbl(xmlCursor);
XWPFTableRow tableOneRowOne = tableOne.getRow(0);
tableOneRowOne.getCell(0).setText("Hello");
tableOneRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("World");
```